# What is the difference between "break down the wall" and "break the wall down"?

Tags: word-order, phrasal-verbs

Could anyone tell me the difference between"break down the wall" and "break the wall down"?

What would be the correct usage?

Comment: There's no difference in meaning, and no particular concensus among native speakers as regards whether it's more natural to position the object *(**the wall**)* AFTER or WITHIN the phrasal verb *(**to break down**)*. For learners, by far the most important aspect of such usages is the matter of how the syntax works if the object is a PRONOUN (it's always *Break **it** down,* never *Break down **it***).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Break down the wall* is far more idiomatic than *break the wall down.***

Despite no real difference in meaning, here is the relevant Ngram:

[image]

This pattern seems to apply to many other nouns as well (e.g. *house*, *data*, *problem*, *door*).

**Use *break down the wall*.**

Comment: I don't know why that *particular* pair shows such a strong bias towards having the "object" ***after*** the phrasal verb, but it certainly doesn't apply to [*break the problem down / break down the problem.*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?smoothing=3&corpus=26&content=break+the+problem+down%2Cbreak+down+the+problem&year_end=2019&year_start=1800&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbreak%20the%20problem%20down%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbreak%20down%20the%20problem%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica I find it strange that the Ngram wouldn't show both if they were so close together. I thought it showed the top results, but apparently not.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica I took out the entire section because I wildly misinterpreted the graph.

Comment: I thought your other graph made sense. Can you explain what was wrong with it?

Comment: @EddieKal It did not show the top results, for example, it showed *break the house down* but not the more common *break down the house*. So it lead to wrong conclusions.

Comment: Well, all I know is that ***far more idiomatic*** in the first sentence of this answer didn't particularly strike a chord with me. I've just checked **break down the x** and **break the x down** in Google NGrams (with x as "wild card" asterisk), to find that ***the door*** is by far the most common "object", and the difference between putting that ***after*** or ***within*** the phrasal verb is still present, but it's only a 2:1 preference. And with more "figurative" objects like ***problem, task, process***, there's no particular preference at all. So I feel I must downvote as "misleading".